# Edit user Permission is greyed Out sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, office-365, designer-workflow

I was trying to edit user permission for a GRP, found that its greyed out, and doesn't allow to make any changes. I have full control access to the site.

[image: dit]

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is not issue with the permission - it is the issue with master page UI. To troubleshoot this make sure - that particular user has at least **READ** access to the **Master Page Gallery** library - you will find this from the site settings page -> Web Designer Galleries section (to get this option listed, you need to activate the SharePoint Server Publishing Infrusture feature).

As an alternative to a quick fix, directly you can access the edit user permission page by the below URL:

```
https://globalsharepoint2020.sharepoint.com/sites/CustomSearchRND/_layouts/15/editprms.aspx?obj=%7B3C4F1C6E%2D07FA%2D4AE3%2DA028%2D3803C03F0945%7D%2CLIST&sel=5
```

[image: Edit User Permission Issue]

Note:

- In the above URL, replace the example demo URL with your site URL.

Comment: Hi - if it has helped you, could you please [Upvote(^)] and mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Since your site is connected to an Office 365 group, you cannot change this through UI interface. You could change the permission level of groups by running PowerShell.

For example: Change members group’s permission from edit to contribute.

```
$AdminCenterURL = " https://domain-admin.sharepoint.com"
$SiteURL = " https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename"
Connect-SPOService -url $AdminCenterURL -Credential (Get-Credential)
Set-SPOSiteGroup -Site $SiteURL -Identity "your group name" -PermissionLevelsToRemove 
"Edit" -PermissionLevelsToAdd "Contribute"
```